# Google Cloud AISE PyTorch NVidia GPU Production - Python3.6 missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The Software versions for this VM says
PyTorch 0.4.1, Python 3.6.3, CUDA 9.2.148.1, cuDNN 7.2.1

but after spinning the vm, I am seeing Python 3.5.3

## jetware

Answer (score 1):

How are you checking the Python version?

I have the same machine and I do have the python 3.6.3

```
@pytorch03-python3-cuda91-1-vm:/jet/prs$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Can you check using this command `python --version`

Maybe you are seeing the pre-installed versions that Debian has (mentioned in the previous comment)

```
@pytorch03-python3-cuda91-1-vm:/jet/prs$  ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.5   /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.5m
```

This is the version I installed:
[image: AISE software installed]

This are my server details:

```
Linux pytorch-python-cuda-minilab-1-vm 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb
9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Dec 19 20:49:00 2019 from 74.125.45.66
# AISE Data Science Lab
### AISE PyTorch 0.4.1 Python 3.6 CUDA 9.2 Notebook
#### Main components
* PyTorch 0.4.1
* Jupyter Notebook 5.1.0
* Python 3.6.3
* CUDA 9.2.148.1
* cuDNN 7.2.1
* NVidia drivers 396.51
* OpenBLAS 0.2.20
* cc 4.9.4
* git 2.14.3
* Python numpy 1.13.3
[Web page](http://jetware.io/appliances/aise/pytorch041_python3_cuda92_notebook-180916?us=googlecli)
[Support](http://jetware.io/contacts/submit/support_googlecl?product=aise/pytorch041_python3_cuda92_notebook-180
916)
### [AISE](http://aise.ai/)
AISE is a platform, software distribution, tools and services for Machine Learning and Big Data.
### [Data Science Lab tools](http://aise.ai/constructors/aise_data_science_lab/appliances)
AISE Data Science Lab is a set of ready-to-use fully integrated and configured software stacks for research and 
development of machine learning and data analytics models.
```

Can you see if you have the python 3.6 installed, try using next command:

```
sudo find / -name python3.6
```

Comment: <myusername>@pytorch03-python3-cuda91-1-vm:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
<myusername>@pytorch03-python3-cuda91-1-vm:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3

Did you install python 3.6 yourself?

Comment: I have edited my comment in order to share a screenshot with you, can you please take a look of the version you installed to see if it matches with the one I have and also you can try the command to find the python version files (all is in my main post)

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation [Choosing an Image](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images), it states that the python versions available are 2.7 and 3.5:

> Pre-installed packages.
>
> All images are based on Debian 9 "Stretch", and
>   include:
>
> The listed framework (for example, TensorFlow) and supporting
>   packages.
>
> - CUDA 9.0/9.1/9.2/10.0/10.1 (GPU only; version depends on framework)
> - CuDNN 7.* and NCCL 2.3.* (GPU only; version depends on CUDA)
> - Python (2.7 and 3.5) with the following packages:
>       numpy,
>       scipy,
>       matplotlib,
>       pandas,
>       Jupyter notebook/lab,
>       nltk,
>       Pillow,
>       scikit-image,
>       Opencv-python,
>       sklearn.

Comment: I am confused about why jetware would mention Python 3.6.3 for their marketplace VM if it comes with Python 3.5. Or am I missing something?